# Cann't find ActionError class in Apache Struts 1.3.10

Tags: struts, struts-1

I follow the tutorial in book `JakataStruts live` (2004). I have code snippet:

```java
@Override
public ActionErrors validate(ActionMapping mapping, HttpServletRequest request) {
ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();

if(firstName == null || firstName.trim().equals("")){
    errors.add("firstName", new ActionError("userRegistration.firstName.problem"));
}
//...
return errors;
```

Netbeans IDE notice that: "Cannot find symbol". How to resolve the above problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Class `ActionError` is deprecated. Use `ActionMessage` class:

```
errors.add("firstName", new ActionMessage("userRegistration.firstName.problem"));
```